# What does the Lagrange Equation do for State-space systems

Tags: control-theory

I'm not sure if this is a good place to ask this question, but I'm currently taking Control System Design and considering everything is this deriving of equations I'm having a hard time actually seeing what is actually happening. I'm just curious as to what Lagrange Equations actually do in a space-state system, and how it would apply to an actual real life situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to design controllers for physical systems, the first thing you would want to obtain (at least most of the times) is a mathematical model of the system. The mathematical model will be a differential equation which governs the motion of the system and which in many cases can be derived from certain laws such as Newton's Second Law of Motion or the Lagrange Equations.

So, Lagrange Equations are used to model a physical system by considering the kinetical, potential energy of the system and the generalized forces (even friction) which influence the motion of the system. Having modeled the system, you have obtained the desired differential equation which for example can be:

$$ m\ddot{y} = -ky-c\dot{y} $$ for a simple mass - spring - damper system, where $y$ is the mass displacement, $k$ is the spring constant and $c$ is the damping coefficient. Now, you can easily move to spate space by defining the state variables you feel comfortable with. For example, you can proceed like this:

$$ x_1 = y \Rightarrow \dot{x_1} = x_2$$

$$ x_2 = \dot{y} \Rightarrow \dot{x_2} = -\frac{k}{m}x_1-\frac{c}{m}x_2 $$

To sum up, you first make use of the Lagrange Equations in order to model the physical system (the meaning of modeling a physical system is to come up with a mathematical equation which describes the motion of the system) and then you convert this differential equation into the equivalent state space form (first order ordinary differential equations).

Comment: Guess this is what I get for drifting off and falling asleep when math professors explain the formulas of things. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Don’t forget to accept any of the answers which you feel like better fits to your question in order for the post to be marked as accepted !

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the application of Lagrange Equation and the state-space representation are two separate things.

The Lagrange equation is used in order to derive the mathematical models of a system (i.e. the equations of motion for a mechanical system).

Once you obtain the mathematical model, then you can convert between all different types of represenations:

- differential equations of motion
- Transfer Function
- State Space representaition

So, to sum up, I consider the application of Lagrange equation to a system as a preprocessing step, in order to obtain the mathematical model. One of the facets of the mathematical model is State-space representation.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. That explains why I'm having such a difficult time with it as I'm more focused on the math than the setup. I know now that I'm not doing controls or design as my focus for my major.